# MySQL's IF leave second value blank

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySql's `IF` single line version, how can I specify `do nothing` for the second value? Eg:

```
Update table set col = IF(score < 10,1, #Do nothing if it's > 10) where userId = 5
```

So, if the score were `< 10`, then do the update or else do nothing. Is this possible, or is there another way to do it perhaps? Seems like I need to supply a value there compulsarily

Comment: you can just supply the same `col` and it wouldn't update

Comment: @TinTran But there's no way to leave it blank?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do this:

```
Update table set col = IF(score < 10,1, col) where userId = 5
```

Answer (score 2):

You can alter the `WHERE` clause like this:

```
UPDATE <table>
SET <column> = 1
WHERE userId = 5 AND score < 10
```